# Randomly sort rows within group

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, data-wrangling

I have a data frame (df1) that has several runs within a given group. Now, I would like to shuffle the runs within a given group without changing the overall structure of the data frame. With that I mean that column 1 (Group) should stay untouched but the order of the second column (Run) should be shuffled within the row range of that group. The desired result is given in df2.

```
df1 <- structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "C", "C"), Run = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L
))

df2 <- structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "C", "C"), Run = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L
))
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `dplyr`: You can fist define your groups with `group_by` and then use `sample` with a `mutate` statememt:

```
df1 %>%  group_by(Group) %>% mutate(Run=sample(Run))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `ave` + `sample`

```
transform(
  df1,
  Run = ave(Run, Group, FUN = sample)
)
```